# CCAvenue payment navigation back to Magento 2.3 on react native issue

Tags: magento2.3

I'm building **Magento v2.3** project in **react-native**. Also, it has multiple stores.

For **payment gateway** I'm using **CCavenue** using **webview**.

Navigation to CCavenue is done perfectly, but while returning back to the return URL, it doesn't consider the return URL instead goes to homepage URL inside web view giving invalid **formkey** **error**.

I have used CSRF interface in the controller but it still gives the same formkey error.

On website the same code and navigation work flawlessly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using react native cli or react native expo ?